# Displaying Shapefiles using Python?

Tags: python, shapefile

I have some shapefiles, which I want to display in Python.

Is there any code for that?

Comment: How do you want to display them? What would be the viewer in the situation you envisage?

Comment: Google [how to display shapefile in python](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20display%20shapefile%20in%20python&safe=off)

Answer (score 3):

There are several libraries that can achieve this. If you want a pure python-solution ( no wrappers for C-code ..) use [pyshape](https://code.google.com/p/pyshp/) but be aware that it "just" reads and writes shapefiles.

However, Joel Lawhead, the author of pyshape, also shows examples of displaying shapefiles in his book "Learning Geospatial Analysis with Python" (packt), e.g. using the pngcanavas library

Also take a look at the blog post entitled [Essential Python Geospatial Libraries](http://carsonfarmer.com/2013/07/essential-python-geo-libraries/) which gives you a good overview of geospatial python libraries (not just shapefiles).

Comment: It needs you to do the deletes - there's a little cross at right of each.  I hope you do not mind me making a tidy up edit to your answer before I upvote it.